# My keyboard isn't responding bios setting on Lenovo ThinkPad x250

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, thinkpad, bios, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Ubuntu on Windows subsystem for Linux(WSL), but it kept giving me this error. I went to bios and try to enable the virtualization, but my keyboard isn't responding except the F1(help), its disabled and I can't enabled it as the keyboard isn't working.

Comment: This question is off-topic, as it asks to fix a problem with the BIOS and has nothing to do with an official Ubuntu flavor or WSL directly.